# Excel VBA CreateObject("Outlook.Application") causes OLE Error as Outlook 2019 didn't exit properly

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ole, createobject

My Excel VBA program, running on Windows 10 64 bit, sends an email via Outlook. This usually works fine but every so often it hangs with a popup stating "Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action".

This is caused by the following lines:

```
Dim appOutlook, mItem as Object
On Error Resume Next
Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set mItem = appOutlook.CreateItem(0)
' set mItem.To,.Subject,.body fields
mItem.send
Set mItem = Nothing
Set appOutlook = Nothing
```

It seems that Outlook 2019 is not exiting properly (via Alt-F4) and gets stuck in Task Manager. I have no idea why, and I've tried removing Add-Ins. Until I End Task, Outlook won't load and the Excel VBA will generate the OLE error on executing the CreateObject() line, where it hangs until the popup is cleared.

Any idea how to fix this? Ideally VBA shouldn't hang on an error anyway, and of course Outlook shouldn't get stuck on exiting. So two problems really. Most important thing is stop the VBA getting stuck, even if it means the email isn't sent.

Comment: What are you doing with the Outlook application once opened and how are you closing it down when you have finished with it?

Comment: Firstly, `On Error Resume Next` does not have too much meaning in the code context. It only does not let the application to raise the error if it exists. Secondly, if this is all your code, the mentioned behavior does not have too much meaning, too. It looks to mean that an operation done by automation from Excel to Outlook does not end and Excel expects it to finish. So, in order to receive an answer able to clarify the problem, I would suggest you to edit your question and place there the whole used code.

Comment: The problem of Outlook not exiting properly and remaining in Task Manager is independent of the Excel VBA, it happens anyway. I use Alt-F4 to exit Outlook.

Comment: The Excel VBA stops on the CreateObject call so what happens after it is irrelevant, and that call is right at the start of the subroutine so I don't think there is much relevant code to add. CreateObject needs a timeout or something if that is possible?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Delete `On Error Resume Next`.

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions of Outlook exit even if there are still outstanding references to its COM objects - the older versions used to hang until all references were released. The only exceptions now are the `Inspector` and `Explorer` objects: even if they are not visible, holding a reference to them woudl prevent Outlook and exiting. If Outlook hangs after your code touches it, make sure you don't store `Inspector` and `Explorer` objects in global variables.

Comment: I just updated the question to be a bit clearer. Outlook occasionally (once a week) doesn't exit properly (with Alt-F4) independently of the Excel VBA code. It is a problem in its own right. Then when Outlook should have exited but is still lingering in Task Manager I get the OLE error when Excel executes CreateObject(). Ideally CreateObject should generate a timeout error or something instead of hanging until the popup is cleared.

Comment: Regarding Inspector and Explorer objects in the VBA, I did a search for "Explorer" and "Inspector" and only got a handful of InternetExplorer objects. I don't think that is what you are referring to?

Comment: I meant the Outlook objects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector

Comment: There was some VBA in Outlook but I didn't find the word Inspector or Explorer anywhere. Anyway I have deleted the VBA, I guess there's a small chance that may stop it hanging, trouble is it takes a week or two to find out!